# Select characters in formatted string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$str = "*POST BUS*1300*2017-9-1*1*LUSAKA*JEFF SAKALA*";
```

I want characters in between asterisks be put in individual variables, something like:

```
$service = "POST BUS";
$time = "1300";
$date = "2017-9-1";
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Questions like this make me want to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: How consistent is this format? you may need regular expressions or a simple positional array via explode.

Comment: `list(, $service, $time, $date) = explode('*', $str);`

Comment: works perfectly fine, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm right, you could use the explode function for this.

```
$str = "*POST BUS*1300*2017-9-1*1*LUSAKA*JEFF SAKALA*";
$exp = explode('*', $str);
$service = $exp[1];
$time = $exp[2];
$date = $exp[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "*POST BUS*1300*2017-9-1*1*LUSAKA*JEFF SAKALA*";

list($service, $time, $date, $anotherVariable) = explode('*', $str);
```

Comment: why is it that when I try to print other variables its printing POST BUS?

Comment: why do I need a comma before the $service?

Comment: @Bool you need a comma before the `$service` because `$str` begins with an asterisk, so when `explode` splits the string on asterisk, the first item in the result is an empty string. Putting a comma before `$service` in `list` skips that first item.